# Recommended method to refactor variable name in Perl code?

Tags: perl, refactoring

I can use [Perltidy](http://perltidy.sourceforge.net/) to reformat source. Quite useful.

If a source file uses a variable like `@m`, how can I most easily refactor that into something else, e.g. `@miles_travelled`?

Using a regular expression to rename does not appear safe, because a separate variable such as `$m` may also exist (with a different type, in this case a scalar), yet the `@m` variable can be referenced using an expression like `$m[$i]`.

For example, none of the following will be correct for Perl code:

- `s/([\$\@])m/$1miles_travelled/g` # Will rename scalar with same name
- `s/\$m/\$miles_travelled/g` # Will fail to rename accesses of array

Is there a recommended tool or method for safely renaming a variable name in Perl code?

Comment: Neither of the regular expressions will respect Perl's block scoping, which is what makes this hard. You cannot assume a `$m` seen on one line is the same symbol to Perl as another `$m` seen on a different line, without accounting for scope. In addition, soft references will get ignored. However, combined with a look through the affected file and suitable tests, it can be made reasonable (helps if the variables have unique-enough names to start with of course!).

Comment: @NeilSlater I agree, limiting to a scope makes the job that much harder. Though I'm still interested in solutions that ignore scope.

Comment: To do this reliably, you really should be using [`PPI`](https://metacpan.org/module/PPI).

Answer (score 5):

1. The variable `$m` always occurs as `$m`.
2. The variable `@m` always occurs as `@m` or `$m[...]`.
3. The variable `%m` always occurs as `%m` or `$m{...}` or `@m{...}`.

… except with indirect method calls: `new $m[...]` parses as `$m->new([...])`. But we can probably ignore this case (use `no indirect` to make sure).

If we want to cover the first three cases properly, we can

1. replace a scalar by `s/(?<=\$)OLDNAME(?!\s*[\[\{])/NEWNAME/g`
2. replace an array by `s/(?<=\@)OLDNAME(?!\{)|(?<=\$)OLDNAME(?=\s*\[)/NEWNAME/g`
3. replace a hash by `s/(?<=\%)OLDNAME|(?<=[\$\@])OLDNAME(?=\s*\{)/NEWNAME/g`

Note that lookarounds or multiple passes for the different cases are neccessary.

Test:

```
use Test::More tests => 3;

my $scalar_re = qr/(?<=\$) foo (?!\s*[\[\{])/x;
my $array_re  = qr/(?<=\@) foo (?!\{) | (?<=\$)     foo (?=\s*\[)/x;
my $hash_re   = qr/(?<=\%) foo        | (?<=[\$\@]) foo (?=\s*\{)/x;

my $input  = '$foo, $foo[1], @foo, $foo{a}, %foo, @foo{qw/a b/}';
my $scalar = '$bar, $foo[1], @foo, $foo{a}, %foo, @foo{qw/a b/}';
my $array  = '$foo, $bar[1], @bar, $foo{a}, %foo, @foo{qw/a b/}';
my $hash   = '$foo, $foo[1], @foo, $bar{a}, %bar, @bar{qw/a b/}';

is $input =~ s/$scalar_re/bar/xrg, $scalar;
is $input =~ s/$array_re /bar/xrg, $array;
is $input =~ s/$hash_re  /bar/xrg, $hash;
```

Comment: You could also have hashes appearing with an array sigil for slices, which complicates things a bit more. For example, creating a hash from a list: `@hash{@list} = (1) x @list`.

Answer (score 0):

The [Padre editor](http://padre.perlide.org/) will carry out a small number of simple refactorings automatically for you. "Rename variable" is one of them.